# Master/Details view for full screen

Tags: desktop-application, master-details, listview, fullscreen

I am creating desktop app with master/details view situation.

In a predefined ratio and size it looks fine.

[image]

When I resize window to full screen it looks something like this:

[image]

What would be a good solution for full screen?

Comment: Surely this is just a dialog box and doesn't need to be maximised?

Comment: It is a main screen of app. I also have some tabs on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options...

1. Widen the listbox and add more columns to it, facilitating more informed item selection.
2. Enlarge the font size to fit the screen space available, easing eye strain.
3. Add a third column to the full screen view and add useful information such as field-level instructions, non-editable fields like record #s and creation dates, examples of acceptable values.

Also, since full-screen landscape forms are the norm for tablets, move your submit and cancel buttons up and to the right, leaving the bottom half of the screen free for the on screen keyboard.

Comment: I actually have readonly records hidden in some tabs. So that will work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that the only thing you can do here is expand the width of the text input fields to 100% and put the buttons in the lower right corner.

You simply don't have enough material to make a full screen look good.

Or just disable full screen on that view.